# How to set thumbnail for movie within iMovie?

Tags: imovie, video-editing

I am currently inserted a manually created thumbnail at the start of a project within iMovie. This works. But.. if i want to add a transition to the starting thumbnail, i lose the thumb in my mac, and in youtube, forcing me to add my custom thumb again.

Seems like a missing piece that I am likely simply not yet noticing how to do.

Thanks for any pointers, drew..